# Make div pop out like a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I currently have a layout made of multiple rows, with 4 columns each. Each column contains a "card" displaying some basic information.

When the user clicks on one of the cards, I want it to make a flip effect to show its back, which contains more detailed information, as well as animate the div to go above everything else, centered, and bigger so I can display a lot more text, and everything without breaking the layout (as a Bootstrap modal would display).

The flip effect is working, but I am now struggling with making the div kind of converting itself into a modal, a.k.a centering itself and zooming in, without scaling the text so I can fit in there more information.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m3 center-align flip-container">
        <div class="flipper">
            <div class="front">
                <div class="card-panel teal" style="position:relative;">
                    FRONT CARD TEXT
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
                BACK OF THE CARD WITH A LOT MORE TEXT, IMAGES AND STUFF
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want check bootstrap, have modals. Else, you need a CSS that make look like modal and with jQuery only add or remove a class.

Comment: I'd recommend to add some example code to your answer

Comment: Already checked bootstrap, went into the materializecss direction instead, it has modals too. However what I want is to transform a div into a modal. I want to transition on the top of other elements, vertically and horizontally centered